# Pins in iOS map exchange their images with each other after playing with map (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, dictionary, xamarin, xamarin.ios, pins

I am developing an app in Xamarin Forms that has a custom map with pins showing logos of the places on the map. All is working well, except that if I play with map a bit (for example move to another position or turn the map and come back) I see that pins exchange their positions. (See the images below)

[This is their initial positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmqFh.png)

[This is what they look like after manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vXru.png)

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: can you show how you create the pins?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe, I solved it myself, thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself.
It turned out that the mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation function was returning wrong annotations each time when it's called to redraw the pin.
I deleted that function and now creating new annotations each time to draw the pin.

Here is the code of the method if somebody faces the same problem:

```
MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
            return null;

        var anno = annotation as MKPointAnnotation;

        if (anno == null) return null;

        var customPin = GetCustomPin(anno);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }
        // commented the following line:   
        //annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Id);
        //if (annotationView == null)
        //{
        annotationView = new CustomMKPinAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Id);

        byte[] resizedLogo = ImageResizer.ResizeImage(customPin.Logo, 32, 32);
        var data = NSData.FromArray(resizedLogo);
        annotationView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
        annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
        annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("logo40.png"));
        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        ((CustomMKPinAnnotationView)annotationView).Id = customPin.Id;
        ((CustomMKPinAnnotationView)annotationView).RestID = customPin.RestID;
        //}
        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        return annotationView;
    }
```

Comment: But you're creating new views all the time which is costly and useless. `DequeueReusableAnnotation` uses the provided ID to re-use views. You should make your ID depend on the image you want to show if you want to solve this the right way. Your problem is typical of `DequeueReusableAnnotation` misuse/misunderstanding.